# Why is a Migration not being created in database?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, migration, database-migration

I connected my app to my database in my settings.py and then ran migrations and my model 0001_initial.py file was created. However, when I try to apply those migrations to the database and create a table, it says no migrations to apply and it doesn't create the table. I don't know why.

Machine 0001_initial.py

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Appear',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('Show', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('Media', models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('TV', 'TV'), ('Radio', 'Radio'), ('Youtube', 'Youtube'), ('Podcast', 'Podcast')], max_length=30, null=True)),
            ('Episode', models.IntegerField()),
            ('Date', models.DateField(max_length=100)),
            ('Time', models.TimeField()),
            ('Producer', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('Producer_Email', models.EmailField(max_length=254)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

Why is the table not being created?

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'machine.apps.MachineConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'crispy_forms',
}]

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'Houston',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST': 'localhost'     
}
```

I've added my settings.py hopefully this helps.

Comment: Can you share the settings of your database? Are you sure it is pointing to the real database, and not for example to an SQLite one?

Comment: You probably haven't configured your connection properly in settings.py. Did you change the default sqlite database? What did you change it to? Also put the code for your database connector from settings.py

Comment: Is this the first time you apply a migration to the db? Are you completely sure the migration was not applied already? If there's been another migration with that name for this app, django wont recognize there's a change

Comment: Ensure that you have the proper folders and files structure. Your django application must include the `migrations` folder including an `__init__.py` file and the  `0001_initial.py` file. Also, ensure that you have declared your application in the applications of your project settings. Then, run the `python manage.py showmigrations` to check which migrations have already been applied. Then, run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to generate and apply the migrations respectively.

Comment: It sounds suspicious that it's your first connection to db and it says that there are no migrations to perform. Usually, when you run first 'migrate' command, you have at least migrations for contenttypes and other build-ins. So it doesn't seem to be connected with model definition, but rather connection.

Comment: @iustitia it has done the contenttypes. it shows that when I run showmigrations. What do you mean by? "So it doesn't seem to be connected with model definition, but rather connection. – "

Comment: @4140tm I have but I cant seem to see it in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my stupid mistake. I was using the master password for the database but on settings.py file. I used the default postgres password that's why it wasn't adding the migration. as soon i changed the password it added it.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'Houston',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST': 'localhost'     
}
```

I changed it and used my master password that I was using to log into my database and it worked.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'Houston',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'A*******',
    'HOST': 'localhost'     
}
```